# Merge sets of overlapping time periods into new one

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

Whats a nice and efficient way in node.js to merge several sets of given time periods into one set that represents the overlap time periods? Periods are provided as starting day and ending day.

```
4 sets of time intervals (days):

 (-------------------------)         (---------)                (---)
                       (------------------------)           (-------)
                 (--------)            (-------)                (----)
       (---------------------)     (---------)     (---)      (-----------)

New set representing overlaps:

                       (--)            (-----)                  (---)
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'd represent the time periods as an array, each item a specific date: `["20170714", "20170715"]`, then intersect two arrays at a time (see [here](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersection)). Once you merged all your sets you'll have to find a way of transforming the arrays to actual time spans.

Comment: @JuanStiza Lodash `intersect` does not what we need here

Comment: @Bergi you are correct!

Comment: There seems to be an additional condition that there must be an overlap in every set. It would help greatly if you provide sample input and output, and what you've tried. As it stands, this is a question about a general algorithm, it's not specific to any particular language or library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge all begin and end timestamps into a single list (storing timestamp and whether it's begin or end) - either naively or using a [more efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#K-way_merging) if you have a lot of sets.

```
  (-------------------------)         (---------)                (---)
                        (------------------------)           (-------)
                  (--------)            (-------)                (----)
        (---------------------)     (---------)     (---)      (-----------)
```

```
  (     (         (     (  )) )     ( ( (     ))))  (   )    ( (((   )))   )
```

Then use a simple increment/decrement scan over time:

```
0 -                                              ----   ------             ---
1 (------                     -------           -)  (---)    (--      -----)
2       (----------         --)     (--         )              (-    -)
3                 (------  -)         (--     --)                (   )
4                       (--)            (-----)                  (---)
```

And collect those intervals where the count is the maximum.

```
                        ^^^^^           ^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^
```